# How to improve Derby database insert time?

Tags: database, jdbc, derby

I have a table with schema and indexes as follows:

```
    create table stop_times
    (
    stop_times_id integer primary key generated by default as identity (start with 1, increment by 1),
    feed_id integer not null,
    trip_id varchar(256) not null,
    arrival_time char(8) not null,
    departure_time char(8) not null,
    stop_id varchar(256) not null,
    stop_sequence integer not null,
    stop_headsign varchar(256),
    pickup_type char(1) check (pickup_type in ('','0','1','2','3')) not null default '0',
    drop_off_type char(1) check (drop_off_type in ('','0','1','2','3')) not null default '0',
    shape_dist_traveled varchar(256),
    timepoint char(1) check (timepoint in ('','0','1'))
    );

    create index stop_times_trip_id on stop_times (trip_id,feed_id);
    create index stop_times_stop_id on stop_times (stop_id,feed_id);
```

Every few days there is a new feed which needs to be loaded into the table and once it loads successfully, the old feed is deleted:

```
delete from stop_times where feed_id=old_feed_identifier;
```

and indexes rebuilt:

```
  cs = db.prepareCall("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_COMPRESS_TABLE(?, ?, ?)");
  cs.setString(1, "APP");
  cs.setString(2, "stop_times");
  cs.setShort(3, (short) 1);
  cs.execute();
  cs.close();
```

The new feed is inserted by reading data from a comma delimited text file line by line. 
Each line is cleaned by removing unescaped quotes, unrecognised columns and manually adding a feed_id.
The cleaned line is then inserted into the *stop_times* table using a prepared insert statement. 
At the beginning of the insert, autocommit is turned off and a manual commit is done every 100 inserts.

This is done middle of the night and works well for most feeds as the whole process only takes a few minutes. 
However there is one feed I'd like to consume which has 20 million records. The speed of insertion that I see on a Ubuntu VM is typically 1000 and 5000 records per second. This adds up to quite a bit of time for 20,000,000 records.

Are there any good tweaks for speeding this up ?

I did try dropping the two indexes above and recreating them afterwards. This gave a performance boost of about 50% which helps but wasn't the gain I would have hoped for.

Comment: Why are you using `SYSCS_COMPRESS_TABLE`? It is inefficient to first release unused space reserved for a table, to then have the system need to allocate a similar amount of space because you want to insert new records.

Comment: The delete and compress happens after the insertion is done Mark. Not directly relevant to the insert but included for completion.

Comment: My point is that you are deallocating space that you'll need again when you're inserting new items: don't deallocate that space. It will be reused automatically.

Comment: I needed to do this as I found query performance was dropping off as new feeds were consumed. Cleaning up the indexes and deleting old feeds seemed to work.